# .reloadData() without reCreating visible cells or those who are in memory?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I have instantiated the third cell, I will add more to my items to my model array and then I will update the collection view data with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
})
```

Everything works as expected. However, when I reload the data for my collectionView, it will instantiate cells that are currently visible or hold in memory (2,3). Unfortunately, I have some expensive server requests which consume a lot of time.

```
Instaniated  0
Instaniated  2
Instaniated  3

******polluting more data: size of cells 10

Instaniated  2
Instaniated  3
Instaniated  4
```

How can I reload the data without reCreating visible cells or those who are in memory?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: then cache the responses from the API if that is too expensive to re-fetch every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the cells, try inserting or reloading the once that have actually changed. You can use `UIColletionView`s `performBatchUpdates(_:)` for this: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates)

An example:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
  self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 1)])
}
```

This ensures that only the new cells are loaded. You can also move around cells and sections in this method and even delete cells. The linked page contains documentation for all of this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! - Unfortunately, I get following error:  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section.

Comment: @JulieNoobie you have insert same value in your array at same index, so that `numberOfCells` count is also maintainable & you have array of data in the same order that you wanted to represent on the tableView. Hope it clears to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you go with below approach

1) I hope you have declared dataSource and collectionView objects as global to the class

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView()
var dataSource = [Any]()
```

2) Have one function to get the initial results from the API response

```
func getInitialPosts(){
    // call api
    // store your initial response in the local array object and reload collectionview
    let results:[Any] = {response from the server call}
    self.dataSource.append(contentsOf: results)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

3) For the next call, you can have another function

```
func getPostsForPage(page:Int){
    // call api with page number
    let newResults = {response from the server call}
    self.dataSource.append(contentsOf: newResults)

    var indexPathsToReload = [IndexPath]()
    let section = 0
    var row = self.dataSource.count - 1

    //add new data from server response
    for _ in newResults {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        row+=1
        indexPathsToReload.append(indexPath)
    }

    // perform reload action
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPathsToReload)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose from your network adapter you are calling delegate function fetchData with new data. Here you have to check if your data is empty or not to check if you need to add new data, or reload entire CollectionView.

Then you create all indexPaths that you need to fetch more, in order to let already fetched cell stay as they are. And finally use insertItems(at: IndexPaths).

I use page in order to paginate new data with page number in the future. Strictly for my use case. Good luck!

```
func fetchData(with videos: [VideoModel], page: Int) {
    guard self.data.count == 0 else{
        self.addNewData(with: videos, page: page)
        return
    }
    self.data = videos
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.isPaging = false
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        self.page = page
    }
}
func addNewData(with videos: [VideoModel], page: Int){
    var indexPathsToReload = [IndexPath]()
    let section = 0
    var row = self.data.count - 1
    self.data += videos
    for _ in videos {
        print(row)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        row+=1
        indexPathsToReload.append(indexPath)
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.isPaging = false
        self.collectionView!.insertItems(at: indexPathsToReload)
        self.page = page
    }
}
```